# Confused about 生气/着急/担心

Tags: word-choice, meaning-in-context, difference, vocabulary, hsk

This is from a random hsk 5 practice exam I found online. [image: picture of hsk 5 practice problem]Confused about the answer to 51 being 生气 here. I chose 着急. My thinking is that 着急 is most similar to anxious in English, which is why the wife was crying. The answer is 生气 though, which I didn’t think would be right because of the whole crying thing. So why can you not use 着急/担心 in this context？

Answer (score 1):

My opinion on this is that 着急/担心 would more or less imply that she is anxious/worried about/of something else that could happen, after that scene. 着急/担心 are for things you are uncertain about, that could turn out bad. Here she is not afraid or uncertain, she's just angry about what has already happened, so 生气 is the right answer. It's not entirely unusual to cry when you're angry.

Answer (score 1):

着急/担心 - worry, feel anxious about something/someone's action that we need to find an answer to it. (Why he is not responsive? I am so worried.)

生气 - anger, a strong emotion that is reacted toward some grievance or **rejection**. (How could he choose to continue watching the game but talk to me? I am furious.)

Answer (score 1):

It's a joke!

I knew a woman, she told me, women often marry someone who is like their father!

This young woman goes to her parents home, because her husband is sitting unresponsive in front of the telly. At home, her dad is doing the same, and her mother has, oddly, gone to her mother's house!

生气！

Maybe a Chinese thing, cry when you are angry:

这个女孩哭着跑回家，因为班上的一些男孩子故意惹她生气。

Answer (score 0):

"着急" refers to feeling anxious or restless due to urgency.
"生气" refers to being angry or upset because of someone's words or actions, "担心" expresses worry or concern about someone or something's well-being or negative outcomes.

In the context you mentioned, his husband was watching tv and did not answer his wife, this is not an emergency or dangerous situation. So 生气 is the best choice.